# D3.js Can not add background image to rectangle

Tags: javascript, css, image, d3.js, fisheye

I'm implementing list of rectangles with d3.js fisheye and want to add a background image to each of rectangles.
I'm trying following thing:

```
 svg.append("defs")
   .append("pattern")
   .attr("id", "bg")
   .append("image")
            .attr("width", 50)
            .attr("height", h)
   .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/4/5/a/1331068897296558865Sitting%20Racoon.svg");

//Create bars
var rectEnter = svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return xScale(i);
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
        return 0;
   })
   .attr("width", function(d,i){return xScale.rangeBand(i)})
   .attr("height", function(d) {
        return h;
   })
   .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return "url(#bg)";
   })
   .attr("stroke",function(d){return 'black';});
```

But still can not make the image appear on the rectangles.
Does anyone has ideas why this happens and how to add the image to ?
Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nitoloz/3HL4a/2555/) with my implementation.

To simplify the case I've created another jsfiddle with image attached to rect, but not working:
https://jsfiddle.net/nitoloz/fd7svrx6/36/

Andrey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the size of the `pattern`:

```
.attr("width", 50)
.attr("height", h)
```

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uzbt1cr6/

Comment: Oh, it really works, thanks!
However I found that the racoons are like "blurred", aren't they?

Do you know if there is a way to add separate images for each <rect> like:

rectEnter
  .append("image")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", 70)
  .attr("height", h)
  .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/4/5/a/1331068897296558865Sitting%20Racoon.svg");

Comment: Do you have any ideas why this image might be not visible?
https://jsfiddle.net/nitoloz/fd7svrx6/36/

Comment: Append the image to the svg, not to the rect: https://jsfiddle.net/dsvbgkL1/ . Regarding your other question, as this is *another* problem, please post another question.